# Connecting to Ubuntu box

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing

I am trying to remote desktop from one Ubuntu machine to another. I can ssh from client to server successfully. On the server machine I set up everything that is mentioned in the guides (Remote Desktop Preferences), but every time I am trying to remote desktop to server from client I get error "Unable to connect". Do I need to set anything up on the server besides what I already did? Can I see somewhere why I couldn't connect?

Comment: Did you install SSH '**server**' on the target machine?  The '**OpenSSH client**' is installed by default on Ubuntu (desktop or server), which allows you to connect **to** a machine that has SSH server. **sudo apt-get install openssh-server**

Comment: Yes, I have it installed. When I tried to connect yesterday and was not successful on the server machine I got message that reads something like "Following machine wants to remote desktop to your machine.", I chose 'Allow' but still couldn't connect.

I should mention that machine I am trying to connect to is a work machine and I am connecting from home. I don't have problem ssh-ing into work machine, but not sure if this is a good indicator that connection can be established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dash, find or search for Desktop Sharing, configure that and you can then graphically control another machine. This sets up a VNC connection that you can use. If there is no one on the other end when connecting to a machine, make sure that you require a password and disable "You must confirm each access to this machine"